# How to perform class nil checks

Tags: swift, swift-class

I have a class in Swift:

```swift
class myClass {
    var theBool : Bool

    init(theBool: Bool) {
        self.theBool = theBool
    }

    init() {
        self.theBool = false
    }

}
```

Elsewhere in my code, I have this check:

```swift
classist  = myClass()

if let daBool = someRandomBool {
    classist.theBool = daBool
}
```

I want to know where to insert this check into the Class.

Comment: It will never be nil so what is there to check?

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like a method that takes an Optional<Bool> and sets it only if it's non-nil?

Comment: @Wizard Basic questions are welcome, but only if accompanied with some kind of evidence that suggests that OP tried to do their own background research before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: Declare the (required) `init` method with an optional parameter type and perform the check there

```
class MyClass {
    var theBool : Bool

    init(bool: Bool?) {
        self.theBool = bool ?? false
    }
}

let someRandomBool : Bool? = true
let classist = MyClass(bool: someRandomBool)
```

or – a bit different but still simpler – with a struct

```
struct MyStruct {
    var theBool : Bool
}

let someRandomBool : Bool? = true
let classist = MyStruct(theBool: someRandomBool ?? false)
```